# favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

Chrome  - source code tab - I see the following in console:

GET http://localhost/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Inside `head` tag I have the following:

```
<link href='ico/favicon.ico' rel='icon'>
```

Click on the above link - opens a new tab with the ico image.

Also tried - without succes:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.ico">
```

Click on the above link says- doesn't exists.

Also I noticed the error message appears only at start and after pressing `Ctrl F5`, and after pressing `F5` only - it dissapears.

Anyway, there is no icon on the browser's tab in any case.

On page tab - console is empty.

Other browsers not tested.

So what is the right way to have an icon and how to avoid the above message?

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems like this with web servers running Linux. Sometimes you need to set the execute bit on the `favicon.ico` file:

```
chmod +rx favicon.ico
```

I've also had to give permissions to the web server service/account to the file:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: why on earth would favicon.ico need the execute bit?

Comment: This worked for me. Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your favicon does exist by going to http://localhost/ico/favicon.ico

and then try ctrl + f5, sometimes caching can ruin things  up.

Comment: `ico/favicon.ico` exists. `Ctrl F5` tried. Clear browsing data - everything except cookies - without success

Comment: Try  "/ico/favicon.ico" as a href

Comment: tried `/ico/favicon.ico` plus `Ctrl F5` - without success. Did you try on your Chrome, pls?

Comment: Can your browser get to the icon if you try visiting the url?

Comment: I tried ans saw something new. Pls see my updated post.

Comment: You need to serve the file as static content, this differs  based on the framework  or the language you're using.

Comment: I'm using `javascript`, `jquery` and `php` what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR**

Things you should try:

- Test with Firefox. If that works, you probably have a `body`-only markup in your `head`.
- Use an absolute path (ie. `/ico/favicon.ico`)

**Explanations**

Browsers try to get `favicon.ico` in the root directory by convention. So this line in the dev console does **not** mean your browser doesn't understand `ico/favicon.ico`. This is more a sign that the favicon markup didn't work for any reason, so your browser is using the "root folder convention" as a fallback.

Using an absolute path (ie. `/ico/favicon.ico` instead of `ico/favicon.ico`) might help you pinpoint the issue, especially if your test page is not `/`.

Chrome has a particular behavior regarding forbidden markups in `head` (eg. `div`, `p`... which are `body`-only markups). When this happens, it considers the `head` section to be closed and thus ignores all `head`-only markups... such as `link`. Consequence: favicon sometimes works everywhere but fails on Chrome. So this is a good idea to test on another browser. It the favicon works elsewhere, look carefully at your `head` and try to spot a markup that shouldn't be here. W3C validator might help.

Answer (score 0):

As Philippe said check that you don't have any wrong in your head tag. In my case I was printing a value with an echo function (php code). Removing it resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using tailwind and encountered the above error, I simply fixed it by
going back to my public folder and deleted the index.html page and recreated it back then paste

`<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"rel="stylesheet"/>`

in the head section and it was fixed.